# Multi-threading scheduler does not work properly

Tags: java, multithreading

I am currently working on optimizing the core of my small file synchronizer. For this purpose I wrote the following class, which takes 2 Endpoints (one of which is a local SSD on my computer and the otherone a remote SSH enabled server with a slower HDD) as an input. The purpose of this class is to make sure file reconciliation can already take place while still searching through the files. However the Java Thread scheduler seems to always prefer the local endpoint over the remote one.

Is there any code specific reason for this? I already tried to use `Collections.synchronizedMap()`, two instances of `ConcurrentSkipListMap` and my latest attempt features the `lock` object and a synchronized block as displayed below.

```
public class FSComparator implements Runnable, FSCheckCompleteListener {

    private final Map<String, FSEntry> entries1;

    private final Map<String, FSEntry> entries2;

    private final Consumer<FSModification> mod;

    private final Set<FSEntry> watchList;

    private final AbstractEndpoint<?> e1;

    private final AbstractEndpoint<?> e2;

    private final String dir1;

    private final String dir2;

    private final AtomicInteger completeCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public FSComparator(String dir1, String dir2, AbstractEndpoint<?> e1, AbstractEndpoint<?> e2, Consumer<FSModification> mod){
        // initialization
    }

    @Override
    public void complete() {
        if (completeCount.incrementAndGet() == 2){
            checkWatchList();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    e2.getFiles(dir2, (f) -> !f.equals(".DS_Store"), (entry) -> {
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            //System.out.println("e2");
                            entries2.put(entry.getFilename(), entry);
                            FSEntry other = entries1.get(entry.getFilename());

                            // perform checks against Endpoint e1 involving checksums etc.
                            // if the file cannot be found in the other Endpoint yet it is 
                            // added to the watchlist which is being checked at the end 
                            // when both threads finished
                        }
                    }, this);
                } catch (EndpointException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            t2.start();

            Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    e1.getFiles(dir1, (f) -> !f.equals(".DS_Store"), (entry) -> {
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            //System.out.println("e1");
                            entries1.put(entry.getFilename(), entry);
                            FSEntry other = entries2.get(entry.getFilename());

                            // perform checks against Endpoint e2 involving checksums etc.
                            // if the file cannot be found in the other Endpoint yet it is 
                            // added to the watchlist which is being checked at the end 
                            // when both threads finished
                        }
                    }, this);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            t1.start();

            t2.join();
            t1.join();
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkWatchList(){
        // final check of remaining entries in the watchlist
    }
}
```

Also it does not matter whether I start Thread t2 first, still t1 is being preferred. Maybe I am overlooking something with regards to multi-threading.

Comment: First of all, is there any reasons why you're calling threads inside a thread? Secondly, I don't see any `notify()` nor `notifyAll()`, and the last one, what is the problem with "always prefer the local endpoint"? -- You can't decide which thread will run first after all.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I forgot to add the calls to ```notify```. Strangely enough, it did work though. The problem with "always prefer the local endpoint" is that my program will then end up stuffing all the files found by Endpoint e1 into the watchlist so that basically running it simultaneously is invain.

Comment: If you must run second thread first, then what you will need is a volatile boolean -- lets say this value is `false` by default; first thread needs to check this var then lock it by the synchronized block, thus second thread will run and then notify the first thread after it has done its job.

Comment: I don't strictly need to run the second thread first, I just want them to execute simultaneosly. The result should not be that one thread claims all the CPU time for itself but rather also grants the second thread the possibility to do its work

Comment: It that case, set its priority or use `yield()`.